# TableLayout was not found

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wanted to use TableLayout nevertheless seems it's not available. What could be wrong?
Check below:
[image: Table Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableLayout` is a **Xamarin.Android** not a **Xamarin.Forms** Layout. Read more about the table layout [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/table-layout) In Xamarin.Forms you use `TableView`, read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview).

You write Xamarin.Forms views usually in `.xaml` files with `.xaml.cs` code behind. You write native Android views in `.axml` or `.xml` with no code behind.

A table for native android;
`table_content.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Open..."
            android:padding="3dip"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

A Xamarin.Forms sample table view;
`TableContentPage.xaml`

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <TableView Intent="Settings">
       <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Ring">
                <SwitchCell Text="New Voice Mail" />
                <SwitchCell Text="New Mail" On="true" />
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</ContentPage>
```